# Transferring incoming communication to another computer

Tags: communication, windows-server-2008-r2, portforwarding, bridge

I have two computers, A and B.

On computer A, I want to be able to specify for certain ports that incoming traffic from computers  will be automatically routed to a different port on computer B as if it was originally sent to B from .

I'm not really sure what I need here. I thought it might be `port forwarding`, `bridge`, `ip routing` or `ip forwarding` but was unable to come to a conclusion.

I'm trying to do this on a Windows 2008 machine, in order to shift traffic from an older software on one server to a newer software on a different server. I tested my trials using http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows, trying to send stuff from my computer to another computer which was supposed to route it back to me, but nothing was received.

I have tried:
http://www.simpleportforwarding.com
but that didn't work for me.

I've also tried:
http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php
but my Anti-virus blocks it (though it's not a malware, as far as I know).

I know Windows has the command "route" on the shell but I'm not really sure what to do with it as it requires a mask for the IP and doesn't seem to allow choosing ports (and it might not be what I need anyway).

I've also come across this:
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/NAT_Windows_2003_Setup_Configuration.html
and though I'm pretty sure NAT is not what I need, maybe that "Roles" configuration has something relevant.

Had anyone come across a similar situation and knows how to solve this? I'm pretty sure there's something ready which can do this and no software needs to be written.

EDIT:
I've discovered that `netsh` can do the above by:

```
C:\>netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=12345 listenaddress=192.168.1.1 connectport=443 connectaddress=192.168.1.1
```

which is a command I found here:
http://www.rickwargo.com/2011/01/08/port-forwarding-port-mapping-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

But the problem is, and I forgot to mention this, I also need to be able to do this routing only for specific source IP addresses. I'm not sure if `netsh` can do this (maybe it can?) so is there any other way?